# C++ variadic template method in a template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class :

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() {//...}
        
        template <typename First, typename... Args>
        Foo(First first, Args... args) {//...}
};
```

Then in my `main.cpp`

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<Abc> foo {0, "some", 20, true, "parameter that Abc::Abc() need", {0, 2, 3}};

    return 0;
}
```

The probleme is that when I compile, I get the following error :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Foo<Abc>::Foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

What is wrong ?

**Edit**

I add `{0, 2, 3}` to the parameters.

The probleme come from here. I didn't specify the type of the parameter and that why it was causing probleme.

Comment: please post the code that produces the error you ask about, rather than other errors: https://godbolt.org/z/aPnK8qx4b.

Comment: after adding an `Abc` and fixing the method definitions there is no error:https://godbolt.org/z/6MvYz1z6E

Comment: code works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49a7cdf918fd5450

Comment: Are you sure in your actual code you have `Foo<Abc> foo {0, "some", 20, true, "parameter that Abc::Abc() need"}` and not `Foo<Abc> foo({0, "some", 20, true, "parameter that Abc::Abc() need"})`?

Comment: `{0, 2, 3}` doesn't have a type, so none can be deduced.